# How to do load testing on long polling?

Tags: websocket, signalr, load-testing, long-polling

I'm trying to figure out how to do load testing on a long polling or web socket type of architecture.
I need to setup multiple clients which subscribe to channels on one side and wait for responses. The load testing should measure the time it took for messages from the publishing server to reach the clients.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Performance#generating-client-load-with-crank),

> SignalR uses a particular protocol to communicate so it's best that
>   you use our tool to generate load for testing your server(s).

So, SignalR comes with [Crank](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank). Crank can only connect to PersistentConnection based apps and not Hub based app.

[This another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628926/what-is-the-best-way-to-load-test-a-signalr-hubs-application) could help you for Hub based app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [crank](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Crank), as referred above. One of the parameters is Transport, so you can specify only LongPolling:

```
crank.exe /Url:http://someUri /Transport:LongPolling
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JMeter (https://jmeter.apache.org/) and flood with http connections with transport-type as header.